# MySQL - How to optimize my query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm so bad in making good MySQL queries. I've created this one:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  `products_stock`.`products_id`,
  `products_stock`.`products_stock_attributes`,
  `products_stock`.`products_stock_quantity`,
  `products`.`manufacturers_id`,
  `products_description`.`products_name`
FROM `products_stock` 
  LEFT JOIN  `products`
    ON  `products_stock`.`products_id` = `products`.`products_id` 
  LEFT JOIN  `products_description`
    ON  `products_stock`.`products_id` = `products_description`.`products_id` 
  LEFT JOIN  `products_to_categories`
    ON `products_stock`.`products_id` = `products_to_categories`.`products_id` 
WHERE `products_stock`.`products_stock_quantity` >=3
  AND `products`.`products_status` = 1
  AND ISNULL(`products`.`products_image`) = false
  AND `products`.`products_image` != ""
  AND EXISTS(
   select * from `allegro`
   where `products_stock`.`products_id` = `allegro`.`product_id` 
     and `allegro`.`attributes` =  `products_stock`.`products_stock_attributes`
  ) = false
```

`products` Table have about 17k rows,
`allegro` Table have about 3k of rows.

The query Idea is select all products, where stock_quanity > 3, where is photo, and where is no product id in `allegro` table.

Now the query takes about 10 seconds. I have no idea how I can optimize it.

@SOLVED

I've added indexes to allegro.product_id and allegro.attributes and now query tooks less than half of second. Thanks all for help

Comment: Have you put any index in the database?

Comment: Please post what EXPLAIN returns and all the table schema.

Comment: There you have explain query result: http://scr.hu/0an/q09nm

Comment: If the issue is solved, simply accept the appropriate answer. If the solution isn't in any of the provided answers, feel free to write an answer yourself and [accept that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/188688).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `EXISTS ( SELECT … ) = FALSE` stuff.

Turn that into something along these lines:

```
LEFT JOIN allegro
          ON products_stock.products_id = allegro.product_id
         AND allegro.attributes = products_stock.products_stock_attributes
…
WHERE allegro.product_id IS NULL
```

See the [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) chapter in the MySQL docs.

Further suggestions:

- Don't join with tables you don't use, like `products_to_categories`
- Instead of `ISNULL(…) = FALSE` write `… IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I've converted all tables to InnoDB, I have removed EXISTS() stuff and added LEFT JOIN allegro as you suggest. I have removed ISNULL(...) and used IS NOT NULL. Query is slow as before, maybe faster by 1 second.

Comment: Please post updates `EXPLAIN` output. Also what number of result lines will the query yield? If that is substantially less than 17k, then identify the condition in your query which excludes most of the ommitted products, and make sure that there is an index to provide that decision quickly.

Comment: WOW, I have added index to `allegro`.`product_id` and `allegro`.`attributes` and now query tooks less than 1 second! Thanks all for help. I have no idea that indexes are so important. Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: @PiKey, note that usually a query can use only one index per table, but an index can span multiple columns. So as you join `allegro` using both of the named columns, you probably should combine them into a single index, at least for this query. And do you have a key for `products_id` in all the other tables?

Answer (score 0):

Before trying following methods, check your tables engine set to innoDB and it is indexed properly, then you can try [straight join](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/straight-join-tutorial/). It will force the look into the left table first.

Another method is using [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php) for slow queries. You can cache the query result into an array by using this method, that avoids querying db frequently. cached results can be updated after specified period of time.